Jetpack compose type mistmatch error for Typography
I created a material 3 theme here and downloaded it to my android studio project. In my android studio project, I updated Color.kt, Type.kt, and Theme.kt with the new theme.
I am now running into this error:
Type mismatch.
Required: androidx.compose.material3.Typography
Found: kotlin.text.Typography

in this code (Theme.kt):
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography, // at Typography
        content = content
    )

I can't find out why online, and this is stumping me since it's a new project with only an updated theme.
In case it helps, my build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.x"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.x"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.text.google.fonts)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}


You should ensure if you have setup a correct Material3 Typography as per this page
Once you have done that, you should ensure you have the correct import
Maybe you've imported the Typography class from the kotlin.stdlib package
But you should import the Typography class mentioned above i.e. this

Yep that's me thinking that I wouldn't have to edit the exported files from the material builder - I noticed that the variable was called AppTypography in Type.kt instead of Typography, so renaming the variable Typography to AppTypography in Theme.kt worked (based on the doc you posted). Thanks!
